# Babel: Function parameter types in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

If I write the following piece of code and transpile it through **Babel (6.5.0)** it works correctly.

```
function foo (first: string, second: number) {
    // code here
}
```

`: string` and `: number` are just removed from the transpiled ES5 code.

If I call the function using wrong parameter types, it does not result in any error/warning. They are informative even though do not have any functionality.

I cannot find proper information about ES6's parameter typing on internet. Is parameter typing even part of ES6?

**EDIT:**
This question got answered in the comments below and I wrapped the official answer based on them.

Comment: No, there is no type hinting in ES6

Comment: No, they are not ES6. They're most likely Typescript or Flow annotations. Check your transpiler settings.

Comment: Why Babel transpiler does not result in error if them are defined?

Comment: @CuriousSuperhero - Bit of a shot in the dark, but are you using the React preset for Babel? Because that contains a plugin that [strips type annotations](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/).

Comment: @JoeClay I'm using babel-preset-react

Comment: Which contains the flow plugin: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

Comment: @CuriousSuperhero - Then that's why you're not getting errors :) The `syntax-flow` and `transform-flow-strip-types` plugins included in `babel-preset-react` make it so errors are not thrown when type annotations are encountered, but do not actually process them - for that, you need to use the [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) tool itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Thanks for [Joe Clay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5436257/joe-clay), [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) and [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for the answers in the comments section. I wrapped the answer below from the discussion as no-one answered officially.*

--

It seems that some **Babel** plugins (eg. [babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/)) strip parameter types off while transpiling. I'm using [babel-preset-react](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) that includes [babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/).

Example behaviour of **babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types** copy-pasted below from http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/

**In:**

```
function foo(one: any, two: number, three?): string {}
```

**Out:**

```
function foo(one, two, three) {}
```

Conclusion, parameter types are not valid ES6, but them can be used if
code is transpiled using Babel with the stripping plugins.